# How to log all outgoing links generated in a view?

Tags: views

What is the most lightweight method of tracking all outgoing links generated in a view. By lightweight I mean that I don't want to have to load a module such as `statistics` that will potentially slow down my site due to it going above and beyond my needs.

Basically I would need to record the data into a database using the following structure:

```
product_id | uid | timestamp
```

The product id is associated with each link and is a separate field. The purpose would be to create sets of clicked links for each user, product, etc. This could in turn be used as a dataset for subsequent user/item analysis. I would imagine I would need to use some sort of callback function.

Can anyone provide an example or any hints?

Comment: Timestamp of what, exactly? And why do you have to log Views results? Views queries I can understand, but results? And please, try to rewrite this in a non-opinion-based way. Currently it heavily depends on your definition of "lightweight".

Comment: By timestamp I mean the time that the link was clicked. It doesn't have to be exact, so for that I can simply use the database insert time. The need for the product id - uid relationships is for developing recommendation engines.

Comment: Oh, so you want to count *clicked* links, not *generated* ones. That explains a bit. Could you please [update your question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/111185/edit)?

Comment: are you opposed to using google analytics event tracking? It is ideally suited for capturing the information you describe, and is done via javascript.

Comment: I would prefer a different method.

Comment: _the most lightweight method_ is rather subjective. In which terms do you define _lightweight_ a method? Also, this question is too broad: We cannot list all the possible methods hoping to find the one you think most lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to attach a click event to each link that triggers an ajax request to record the click.

The problem with this is that the page may redirect before the ajax request has had a chance to fire so you will have to prevent the default action of the click, and then perform an ajax request with async=false, and then provide a call back function to redirect to the links destination.

Not exactly lightweight...

Another option is to define an outbound link function in PHP that will accept the final destination as a argument. So the link would look like `/outbound?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`.

Then in that function you can record the click, and then redirect them on to the destination passed in...

Comment: The second option sounds like a good option. Is there any reason why the second one would not be ideal?

Comment: I've actually used the second option before and it worked fine. I guess I feel that because Google analytics is designed specifically for doing this stuff that it will work better than my solution, so for me to call my solution "ideal" I have to be more intelligent than all the programming bods at Google, so I'm reluctant to make that claim...